# Вывод ошибок и уведомлений

Tags: javascript

Всем здравствуйте. 
Помогите с выводом ошибок при загрузке файлов. А именно: скрипт формы обр связи имеет функцию прикрепления файлов.
В случае ошибки выводится сообщение в теге `<p>....</p>` и по дефолту все работает отлично, но я использую [плагин](http://dimox.name/jquery-form-styler/) стилизации для чекбоксов, инпутов и прочего и он меняет порядок кода в html, а как я понял он важен.

По умолчанию без плагина конструкция html такая:

```
<!-- Файл -->
<input type="file" name="images[]">
<p style="color: #000000; margin-top: 9px; margin-bottom: 9px;"></p>
```

С плагином:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить и сделать вывод уведомлений? Может можно как то по айди их выводить? Я в этом двоешник) Так что если что, не прогоните уж)

Вот кусок скрипта который все это дело выводит:

(я не использую возм прикрепления нескольких файлов. В настр скрипта стоит 1)

```
$(document).on('change','input[name="images[]"]',function(e){
// если выбран файл, то добавить ещё элемент "Выбрать файл"
if ((e.target.files.length>0)&&($(this).next('p').next('input[name="images[]"]').length==0) && ($('input[name="images[]"]').length<countFiles)) {
  $(this).next('p').after('<input type="file" name="images[]"><p style="color: #ff0000; margin-top: 9px; margin-bottom: 9px;"></p>');
}
// если выбран файл, то..
if (e.target.files.length>0) {
  // получить файл
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  // проверить размер файла
  if (file.size>maxSizeFile) {
    $(this).next('p').text('Файл не будет отправлен, его размер больше 10 мб');
  }
  // проверить тип файла
  else if (!file.type.match(typeFile)) {
    $(this).next('p').text('Ошибка: Файл не является zip архивом.');
  }
  else {
    // убираем сообщение об ошибке
    if ($(this).next('p')) {
      $(this).next('p').text('');
    }
  }
}
else {
  // если после изменения файл не выбран, то сообщаем об этом пользователю
  $(this).next('p').text('Файл не будет отправлен, т.к. он не выбран');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что не выводится ошибка?

Тогда используйте id для вашего p тега, например

```
<p style="color: #000000; margin-top: 9px; margin-bottom: 9px;" id="p_tag"></p>
```

Тогда ваши селекторы из $(this).next('p') превратятся в $('#p_tag')

```
$('#p_tag').text('');
```

И объявите его 1 раз в самом верху функции: var element = $('#p_tag') и пользуйтесь.